# Serialize an anonymous JSON array without keys

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, anonymous-types

I have an anonymous JSON object and I need to add a list of strings (parameter: productOptions) to it. I need to put them into a keyless JSON-array. How would I do that with anonymous types?

```
public static List<Product> getProductsByProductOptions(long salespartnerGroupID, string marktCode, long producttypeGroupID, long productvalueGroupID, long deviceGroupID, List<string> productOptions)
{
   RestRequest request = newRestRequest("getProductsByProductOptions");
    
   var jsonObj = new
   {
      input = new
      {
         spbgid = salespartnerGroupID,
         code = marktCode,
         producttypegid = producttypeGroupID,
         productvaluegid = productvalueGroupID,
         devicegid = deviceGroupID,
         productOptions = new { item = productOptions }
      },
   };
    
   IRestResponse response = GetResponseAndSerialize(jsonObj, request);
    
    
   BaseProduct myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseProduct>(response.Content);
    
   return myDeserializedClass.@return.item;
}
```

I need the JSON to be like this:

```
"input": {
    "spbgid": 3797,
    "code": "xxx",
    "producttypegid": 5239,
    "productvaluegid": 0,
    "devicegid": 4030,
    "productOptions": {
        "item": [
            "SCREEN_PROTECTOR", "REPLACEMENT"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What JSON does your code produce right now?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but using the RestSharp.JsonSerializer instead of JsonConvert fixed the problem. The anonymous object seemingly works just fine.